# Mapbox - extrude buildings in 3D with custom height from database?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox GL JS to extrude buildings in 3D just like it's done in the official documentation:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/

However, now I want to change the height of certain buildings with my own from a MySQL database.
I imagined it would work if I just compared the ID of the bulding from OSM, however, the Mapbox 'building' source layer doesn't have an ID field: https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#building

What's my best solution to this problem? I see that similar questions have been asked before with no solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, now I want to change the height of certain buildings with my own from a MySQL database.

It's not really clear what you mean by this. But in general, without an ID in the vector tile data, it's going to be extremely difficult to join data from some external source. You will probably have to use your own building data rather than the Mapbox data.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I assume the building data is in GeoJSON?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: In what format is the building data that Mapbox uses to render 3D buildings?

Comment: They provide them as Mapbox vector tiles.